# Event occurring in same tab, while opening a link from active tab to new tab in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, addeventlistener, dom-events

```
var extension= {
check_domain : function(domain){
        //checking the domain name where event should occur........
},
on_load: function(e) {
    var doc_event = e.originalTarget;
extension.check_domain(doc_event.location.href);
},
init: function(e) {
if(gBrowser){
    gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.on_load, false);
    }
} } window.addEventListener(  "load", function(e) { extension.init(); }, false);
```

The on_load function is called when new tab or link is clicked. But my problem is that if we are opening new link from an active tab to a new tab, the event that is suppossed to be happening in the new tab happens in the active tab,while the new tab loads in the background.And if we are opening number of links like that all the events occur in the active tab not in the new tab.

What i want is that the event should happen in the new tab even if it runs in the back ground..
How to identify a new tab and get the event to occur in new tab...(optional=>)Without making the new tab the active one.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain how you check in which tab the event happened, I suspect that you simply look at the currently active tab - and that won't work of course if something loaded in a background tab. You should instead look at `e.target` (the document that loaded) and check which tab it corresponds with:

```
on_load: function(e) {
  var doc = e.target;
  var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc);
  ...
},
```

This will give your the `<browser>` element of the tab where the document loaded (might also be `null` if the document loaded wasn't a top-level document).

Comment: Thanks,Browser element made my script easier, but my problem is not solved....... Event that is supposed to be occurring in the new tab is still occurring in the old tab.......Please help..